# Find the user's location and display it in pop up in a single post back

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Needed to display the  user's geo location (ZipCode) and display it during page load. Currently I am achieving this by 2 post backs, is there any way to achieve within a single post back.

Thanks

What I have tried:

```
function ShowMessages() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    } else {
        alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
    }
    function success(position) {
        debugger;
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng},
            function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {
                        var searchAddressComponents = results[0].address_components,
                            searchPostalCode = "";
                        $.each(searchAddressComponents, function () {
                            if (this.types[0] == "postal_code") {
                                searchPostalCode = this.short_name;
                            }
                        });

                        document.getElementById('hidden1').value = searchPostalCode
                        __doPostBack('', '');


                    }
                }
            });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can find the value of searchPostalCode then display it to span and that span will be move on div which is popuped.

```
document.getElementById('hidden1').value = searchPostalCode;
                    document.getElementById('YourSpan').innerText = searchPostalCode;
                    $("#YourDiv").append($("#YourSpan"));
                    $("#YourDiv").modal();//Apply your modal code here
```